# How do I catch an exception caused from std::map?

Tags: c++

I have declared a map like this

```
map<long long, list<SoundInfo *> > m_soundListMap;
```

and I also have this function

```
void addSoundInfo(long long deviceId, SoundInfo * info)
```

I am trying to add sound info associate with the device id as the key into the map. In this function, I assumed that a key and value pair has been added to the map. So I can retrieve the list of the sound info and add incoming sound info to the back of the list.

I want to catch an exception for the case that the map doesn't have the key then I can create the key and value pair and insert into the map.

How do I catch this exception in C++?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Ehm.. what exactly are you doing in `addSoundInfo`? `std::map` doesn't throw any exceptions on insertion.

Comment: What is going to happen if I try to get the list<SoundInfo *> and the map doesn't have the key? is it just returning null or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is going to happen if I try to get the list and the map doesn't have the key?

Depends on how you try to get the item.

```
list<SoundInfo*>& info_list = m_soundListMap[55];
```

Will create an empty list, insert it into the map and return that when the key doesn't exist yet.

```
typedef map<long long, list<SoundInfo *> >::iterator iterator;
iterator iter = m_soundListMap.find(55);
```

Will return an iterator to the pair that holds both the key and the value, or will be `map::end()` if the key doesn't exist. `iter->second` will be your `list<SoundInfo*>`.

Answer (score 4):

`std::map::operator[]` returns a reference to the entry with the specified key; if no such entry exists a new entry is inserted (with the specified key and a default-constructed value) and a reference to that entry is returned. 
It can throw an exception when allocating memory fails (`std::bad_alloc`).

It sounds like you would probably find [a good introductory C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**map::find**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/) to check if map already has any value associated to a particular key.

Answer (score 1):

You might look up the value using m_soundListMap.find(x).  This returns an iterator.  If the iterator is m_soundListMap.end() then the key wasn't found and you can insert if needed.
No exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this.

```
if(m_soundListMap.find(SomeLongVar) != m_soundListMap.end())
{  
  //Element found, take a decision if you want to update the value  
}  
else   
{  
  //Element not found, insert  
}
```

Comment: you are right. there is no exception, actually a new entry is created if the kety does not exist!
the mystery of C++  :)